# HI, I have some select fields on a wedding site... I achieve that if the people is not going to the wedding the

Tags: javascript

I have web for my wedding. Inside it i have a reservation page where user select if he is going or not. What I want is to hide the food selection field when if the person is not going. I did it with this code but it only apply for the first person in the group when the reservation form has 2 or more people only hide the selects for the first person... How can I do to hide all other guest food selects if they aren't going to.

function bailoteo() {

```
    var rsvbailoteo = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1];
    var food = document.getElementById('food');
    var the_cake = document.getElementById('the_cake');
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    console.log(rsvbailoteo.value);

    if (rsvbailoteo.value == 0) {
        console.log('no estare');
        food.style.display = 'none';
        the_cake.style.display ='none';
        selects[2].value = "none";
        selects[3].value = "none";

    } else if (rsvbailoteo.value == 1) {
        console.log('si estare');
        food.style.display = 'block';
        the_cake.style.display = 'block';
        selects[2].options[0].selected = true;
        selects[3].options[0].selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's complicated to narrow down without the markup. But this example works. Maybe it helps.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].addEventListener('change',function(){
  bailoteo();
});
function bailoteo() {
    var rsvbailoteo = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    var food = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1];

    if (rsvbailoteo.value == 1) {
        console.log('no estare');
        food.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (rsvbailoteo.value == 0) {
        console.log('si estare');
        food.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<select>
 <option value="0">coming</option>
 <option value="1">not coming</option>
</select>

<select>
 <option value="0">pizza</option>
 <option value="1">applepie</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @JuanDanielAcevedo yes send it to duru@axsup.net

Answer (score -1):

getElementById is the problem. An ID is a unique identifier for one single "thing" in the HTML. You should assign a *class* and use this instead.

Comment: Could you give a clue on how to use "this"? Thanks

Comment: That's a comment not an answer

Comment: A class is the way to define a common name to several elements in HTML. The ID is the way to define a unique name to a single element in HTML. Jquery can help you accessing all kinds of names very easily. In the following sample you see two SPANs having different colors. Both are in the class "test". With the single line of code at the end they both get a new color: green. https://jsfiddle.net/1u08dq8b/